# Move gameobject from fixed position to pointposition following curve Unity2d

Tags: unity

I want to move the object from the fixed position to the mouse position according to the curve as shown in the illustration. The altitude is the same and the horizontal distance is equal. [image]

Comment: Have you tried applying [existing answers about parabolic trajectories](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/114675/39518)? There are more under the [tag:projectile-physics] tag, which may give you useful starting points.